# Property 'toDate' does not exist on type 'Date' Angular firestore

Tags: angular, typescript, timestamp, angularfire

I am trying to convert `timestamp` object from Firestore to `Date` object in TypeScript using `toDate()`.

```js
import { AngularFirestore } from '@angular/fire/firestore';
...
constructor(private database?: AngularFirestore) {...}
...
const someVariable = a.date.toDate();
```

Although the functionality is working fine in development mode but I am getting TypeScript compile check error. Also I am not able to build prod version (using `ng prod`) because of this error.

> a.date.toDate() ~~~~ src/app/project/some.service.ts:74:36 -
> error TS2339: Property 'toDate' does not exist on type 'Date'.

Any suggestions how do I resolve this?

Comment: Here a.date is firestore timestamp of form `{seconds: <sec>, nanoseconds: <nanosec>}`. Per documentation to convert timestamp object we need to invoke `toDate()` method, that is what I am doing...

Comment: *"...working fine in development mode..."* Aren't you using TypeScript in "development mode"? Using it in development is its fundamental purpose.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

toDate() does not work on Date, String, Number etc. Change type of your **date** to **any** for Timestamp.

```
date: any;
```

Btw, i would use toDate() usually in html files. It would show error but could compile. Type **any** also will clear html errors.

Comment: But what's the official data type of date provided by Firebase?

Comment: Default types generates error and question was about it. If you use Timestamp (Need Imports from Firebase), probably it works well.

Answer (score 3):

The error is telling you that as far as TypeScript knows, `a.date` is **already** a `Date`, not a `Timestamp`. So you need to look at the type information for whatever `a` is. If it's saying its `date` property is a `Date` when in fact it's a `Timestamp`, that's what you need to fix. (Or of course, if `a.date` is already a `Date`, you don't need that `toDate` call on it. But you said this code was "working in development mode" which suggests it's really a `Timestamp`.)

Comment: No. Here `a.date` is firestore timestamp object of form `a date:  t {seconds: 1598898600, nanoseconds: 0}`

Comment: Then there is a mistake somewhere that makes TypeScript _believe_ that it's a `Date`! Maybe the type definition of your model doesn't match reality. As T.J. Crowder said: "_So you need to look at the type information for whatever `a` is. If it's saying its `date` property is a `Date` when in fact it's a `Timestamp`, that's what you need to fix._"

Comment: @KinleyChristian - Again: *"...as far as TypeScript knows, a.date is already a `Date`...you need to look at the type information for whatever `a` is..."* Because TypeScript clearly thinks it's a `Date`, not a `Timestamp`.